# Add space between name and image in Picker View in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

The following code shows an image and a category name in a Picker View, but no matter what I do I cannot add a space between the category image and the category name, see image below.

Any idea how can I add a space between the name and the image? Is this even possible?

```
 Picker("", selection: $selectedCategory) {
    ForEach(categorySM.categories, id: \.self) { category in
        HStack {
            if let inputImage = UIImage(data: category.image ?? Data()) {

                let resizeImage = inputImage.scalePreservingAspectRatio(targetSize: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30))
                Image(uiImage: resizeImage)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)// doesn't add space
            }
            Text(category.name ?? "")
        }
        .tag(category as CategoryItem?)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe try a `Spacer()` instead of `padding` works?

Comment: Replacing the `padding` with a `Spacer` doesn't work either. I tried adding the `Spacer` before and after the image without luck. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `Picker` is taking your `HStack` apart and using the component views in the way it wants. For example, even if you put the image after the title in the `HStack`, the selected item is still shown with the image first. On the other hand, the list of options that you get when you tap the picker shows the titles first.

I couldn't find any way to get padding to work. But as a simple workaround, you can just prepend a few spaces to the titles:

```swift
ForEach(categories) { category in
    Label("   " + category.name, image: category.imageName)
        .tag(category.id)
}
```

[image: Picker]

Alternatively, you could include some trailing blank space in your images, of course.

Comment: Even though I couldn't use the `Label` as you suggested your suggestion led me to a solution, I basically added an empty string to the category name. Change `Text(category.name ?? "")` to `Text("   " + "\(category.name ?? "")")`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around the picker restrictions by rebuilding it using `Menu`:

```
let categories = [
    "house",
    "hammer",
    "fork.knife.circle",
]


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedCategory: String = categories.first!
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Menu {
            ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { category in
                Button {
                    selectedCategory = category
                } label: {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: category)
                        Text(category)
                    }
                }
            }
        } label: {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: selectedCategory)
                    .padding(.trailing, 10)
                Text(selectedCategory)
                Image(systemName: "chevron.up.chevron.down")
            }
        }
    }
}
```